# Catch the incoming route and redirect back after login

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have an app with login and dahsboard with threads. The particular thread has it's own url address. If i want to share the thread url with someone, he would need  to log-in first and then I need to redirect him back to the thread's url. So basically I need to somehow get the location immediatelly he enters the app, save it to the eg. redux store, and after he successfuly log-in, redirect him back to the thread url. I have everything working except the getting the incoming url.

Now I have this routes.js:

```
const requireLogin = (nextState, replace, cb) => {
  function checkAuth() {
    const { userAuth: { loggedIn }} = store.getState();
    if (!loggedIn) {
      replace('/login');
    }
    cb();
  }
 checkAuth()
}
<Route path="/" component={App}>
  <IndexRedirect to="/dashboard" />
  <Route path="/login" component={LoginPage} />
  <Route onEnter={requireLogin}>
    <Route path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
    <Route path="/thread/:id" component={SingleThread} />
  </Route>
</Route>
```

I my App react component I have:

```
class App extends Component {
 constructor(props) {
  super(props)
 }


 getChildContext() {
   console.log("LOCATION:" + JSON.stringify(this.props.location))
   return { location: this.props.location }
 }
 ...
  render() {
  const { children } = this.props
  return (
    <div className={style.normal}>
    {children}
  </div>
  )
 }
}
```

to get incoming thread's url, but everytime I put eg. /thread/3 the console logs the '/' or the '/login' which I am redirecting to not logged users. Maybe the React Router TransitionHooks could help me, but I don't know how to use it properly in this case.

I am using react-router v2.0.0 with react-router-redux v4.0.2

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: what version of react router are you using?

Comment: Hey QoP, react-router v2.0.0 with react-router-redux v4.0.2

Answer (score 0):

You can try to wrap the private area in a component like ->

```
<Route path="/" component={App}>
  <IndexRedirect to="/dashboard" />
  <Route path="/login" component={LoginPage} />
  <Route component={PrivateWrapper}>
    <Route path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
    <Route path="/thread/:id" component={SingleThread} />
  </Route>
</Route>
```

Your PrivateWrapper should look like this

```
class PrivateWrapper extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
         super(props);
         this.checkIfUserIsValid = this.checkIfUserIsValid.bind(this);
    }
    checkIfUserIsValid(){
        let {user} = this.props.auth;
        if(user == null){
            this.context.router.push("/login");
        }
    }

    render(){
        let {user} = this.props.auth;
        if(user == null)
           return <div></div>
        else{
           return <div>{this.props.children}</div>    
    } 
}

PrivateWrapper.contextTypes = {
    router: React.PropTypes.object
};

export default connect(**Auth state here**)(PrivateWrapper);
```

This way you dont even need hooks or anything.